# How to reclaim unused space in SYSAUX tablespace in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have 6gb file for SYSAUX table space in 18xe oracle database.

SYSAUX table space has 61% free space :

```
    select
       fs.tablespace_name                          as Tablespace,
       (df.totalspace - fs.freespace)              as Used_MB,
       fs.freespace                                as Free_MB,
       df.totalspace                               as Total_MB,
       round(100 * (fs.freespace / df.totalspace)) as Percentage_Free
    from
       (select tablespace_name, round(sum(bytes) / 1048576) TotalSpace from dba_data_files group by tablespace_name) df,
       (select tablespace_name, round(sum(bytes) / 1048576) FreeSpace from dba_free_space group by tablespace_name) fs
    where
       df.tablespace_name = fs.tablespace_name
       and df.tablespace_name = 'SYSAUX';
```

returns

[image]

So I would like to reclaim the 61% free space if possible.

## Attempt 1 :

```
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE '...\XE\SYSAUX01.DBF' RESIZE 5000M;
```

But I'm getting the error :

```
ORA-03297: file contains used data beyond requested RESIZE value
```

## Attempt 2 :

```
ALTER TABLESPACE SYSAUX SHRINK SPACE KEEP 5000M;
```

Error :

```
ORA-12916: cannot shrink permanent or dictionary managed tablespace
```

## Attempt 3 :

```
ALTER TABLESPACE sysaux RESIZE 5000M;
```

Error

```
ORA-32773: operation not supported for smallfile tablespace SYSAUX
```

Does anyone know to relcaim this space please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately SYSAUX is a "special beast" because of its contents. THere are a number of differing mechanisms to reclaim space dependent on the type of objects in there.

The MOS note "Troubleshooting Issues with SYSAUX Space Usage (Doc ID 1399365.1)" is probably the best starting point here, but in all of these cases, its generally pretty rare to be able to get to a point where you can actually resize the datafile downwards because several tables in SYSAUX have LONG columns, and thus you can't do an "alter table move" on them.

Some people have had success with some (unsupported) mechanisms of dropping/recreating certaing objects, but of course this means you need to be prepared to lose whatever information you had in them.

SYSAUX doesn't count toward your XE space limit, but I do understand that having that space sitting there when you now its more than half empty is frustrrating.